# WSO2 DBLookup not returning a JSON result

Tags: wso2, integration, wso2-esb

I'm really new in WSO2 world and I have a DBLookup config as follow:

```
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/consultadb">
        <inSequence>
            <log/>
            <dblookup>
                <connection>
                    <pool>
                        <driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver>
                        <url>jdbc:sqlserver://****.CORP:1433;databaseName=*****;</url>
                        <user>user</user>
                        <password>user</password>
                    </pool>
                </connection>
                <statement>
                    <sql><![CDATA[SELECT NAME FROM CLIENT]]></sql>
                    <result column="NAME" name="getName"/>
                </statement>
            </dblookup>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
            <log/>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
```

But when I run, I didn't get any response in postman... what I'm doing wrong? I already setup a Respond Meditor

There is no errors and the response are 200 OK, in log the final message are:

`[2021-06-25 11:39:31,542]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:salesforceinit} To: /salesforceinit/consultadb, MessageID: urn:uuid:d9ba7fc8-733e-413a-a47b-f7ebac8ae4e3, correlation_id: d9ba7fc8-733e-413a-a47b-f7ebac8ae4e3, Direction: request`

[image: Postman printscreen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is because your query returns more than one element from DB. And **DBLookupMediator** can handle only one row. And that is mentioned in [mediator documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/DBLookup+Mediator+):

> The DBLookup mediator **can set a property from one row in a result set**. It cannot return multiple rows. If you need to get multiple records, or if you have a table with multiple parameters (such as URLs), you can use the WSO2 Data Services Server to create a data service and invoke that service from the ESB using the Callout mediator instead.

If you want to read data from DB, you should use **Data service**. How to create, you can find in documentation: [Creating a Data Service](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Creating+a+Data+Service+from+Scratch+)